# After pakage a python to a exe with pyinstaller, why it can not run on a new computer?

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have two computers , named A(develop computer) and B(open computer);

On A computer ,i installed conda environment,and installer pyinstaller ,fastapi, unvicorn .

I write two python files with pycharm in directory F:\testpyinstaller:
testpyinstallermain.py  /  example.py

testpyinstallermain.py file content :

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('first step check pyinstaller')
    uvicorn_process = subprocess.Popen( ['_internal\\uvicorn', 'example:app', '--host', '127.0.0.1', '--port', '8000', '--log-level=info'])
```

example.py file content:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"hello": "World"}
```

when running the testpyinstallermain.py with pycharm ,it workds normally ,and it can start a web server with uvicorn.

so ,i want to package a exe with pyinstaller and make the exe can be run on B computer.

### The pyinstaller --version : 6.4.0

after use the command :

C:\testpyinsatller>Scripts\pyinstaller.exe -D --add-data="C:\testpyinsatller\Scripts\uvicorn.exe;." --add-data="C:\testpyinsatller\Library\bin\ffi.dll;ffi.dll" --noconfirm testpyinstallermain.py

it produce a exe in directory: C:\testpyinsatller\dist\testpyinstallermain

testpyinstallermain.exe  and a directory : _internal

If i open the testpyinstallermain.exe on the computer A, it can work normally ,and start a web server.

Then i remove it(whole C:\testpyinsatller\dist\testpyinstallermain) to the computer B

and run the exe ,it notice that :

**C:\testpyinstallermain>testpyinstallermain.exe**

first step check pyinstaller

Fatal error in launcher:

## Unable to create process using '"C:\testpyinsatller\python.exe"  "C:\testpyinstallermain\_internal\uvicorn.exe" example:app --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8000 --log-level=info':

How to solve it ?
it maybe lost some dependeces, so i tried to copy the whole C:\testpyinsatller to B computer from A computer ,it can work.

### But i want to know if there is a good way to package whole library the exe need, and computer B no need install runtime enivroments like conda , python etc.

### or is there a simple way to reach the aim;

Comment: `data="C:\testpyinsatller\Library\bin\ffi.dll;ffi.dll"` You have misspelled `installer` as `insatller`...

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry for that ,i make a mistake .  but it should not affect the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pyinstaller should package whole conda enviroment the exe needs.
I tried this way and it worked on computer B.